# How can I sync SID to user profiles when the authentication provider type is Trusted Claims Provider Authentication (ADFS)?

Tags: user-profile-service, user-profile-property, adfs

We are implementing ADFS within our environment but have code that is dependent on the user's SID. The SPUser.Sid is empty due to the switch from classic to claims authentication and thought we could depend on SID in the user profile.

Unfortunately it looks like when we change the authentication type to Trusted Claims Provider Authentication for the user profile sync connection the identity claim is populated into the SID property instead of the actual SID.

Additionally I've tried creating custom profile properties and mapping them to objectSid for various data types and while some data comes across for binary and string types, it's not in the expected format.

Is it possible to sync the SID when the authentication provider type is Trusted Claims Provider Authentication and if so how should I go about accomplishing this?